# Pandas crosstab on dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a dataframe that is storing transaction logs. Every log has its own activity hash and respective user ID, e.g.

```
ID                  UserID
999974708546523127  AU896
999974708546523127  ZZ999
999974708546520000  ZZ999
```

I use crosstab to create a correlation matrix to compare the users activity hashed against each other. Thereby I can measure how similar their behaviour is:

```
Data = pd.read_csv('path.csv', 
        sep=';', names=['ID', 'UserID', 'Info1', 'Info2'], error_bad_lines=False, 
        encoding='latin-1', dtype='category')

df = pd.crosstab(Data.UserID, Data.ID)
```

However, as I have ~5 millions rows and the ID activity hash is that complex, the computation takes way too long or doesn't complete at all. Using `dtype = 'category'` reduced reading time of the csv file significantly already.

**Expected Output Correlation Matrix**

```
Index  AU896  ZZ999
AU896    1     0.5
ZZ999   0.5     1
```

I can not change the hash nor the UserID to reduce memory usage.

**This operations takes 6 and 3 seconds for Info1 and Info2.**

Maybe there is a more efficient operation to do this with pandas or even with dask?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, Have you tried the to transform the data using `pd.pivot()` to create a columns for `AU896` and `ZZ999` and then using `df[['AU896', 'ZZ999']].corr()`

Comment: Can you post a working code example? I tried pivot but failed as my try was to imperformant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure about the use case. As you did not show what to do with `info1` or `info2` column. So I am giving an general example.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data_string = '''ID,UserID,info1
999974708546523127,AU896,35
999974708546523127,ZZ999,45
999974708546520000,ZZ999,13
999974708546520000,AU896,13
999974708546523128,AU896,45
999974708546523128,ZZ999,12
999974708546520001,ZZ999,36
999974708546520001,AU896,37'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string))

# create a wide form of data from long
wide_df = df.pivot(index="ID", columns="UserID", values="info1").reset_index()
# build the correlation metrics from the wide form of data
corr_df = wide_df[["AU896", "ZZ999"]].corr()
```